# Android - PC usb connection - do it without wifi

Tags: java, android, connection, wifi

I wanted to ask how to change following code, which needs USB connection and WIFI to work... (and I don't know why wifi...), to code, which needs only USB cable and NO WIFI!, because I don't want to be dependent on wifi...

Could you please help me? Some changes or additions in code? Thanks.

**Code for Android:**

```
private final Runnable connectToServer = new Thread()
{
@Override
public void run()
{

    try
    {// Get the server address from a dialog box.
        String serverAddress = "192.168.0.23";

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 38300);
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Consume the initial welcoming messages from the server
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }
        solveCube();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
};
private final Runnable initializeConnection = new Thread()
{
@Override
public void run()
{

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(generateCubeString());
    out.println(generateCubeString());
    String response ="";
    try {
        response = in.readLine();
        if (response == null || response.equals("")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    if (response.contains("Error")) {


    } else {
        solveCubeAnimate(response);
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    final String finalResponse = response;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            textView.setText(finalResponse);

        }
    });



}
};
```

**Code for PC**

```
private static class Capitalizer extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
private int clientNumber;

public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
}

/**
 * Services this thread's client by first sending the
 * client a welcome message then repeatedly reading strings
 * and sending back the capitalized version of the string.
 */
public void run() {
    try {

        // Decorate the streams so we can send characters
        // and not just bytes.  Ensure output is flushed
        // after every newline.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Send a welcome message to the client.
        out.println("Hello, you are client #" + clientNumber + ".");
        out.println("Enter a line with only a period to quit\n");

        // Get messages from the client, line by line; return them
        // capitalized
        while (true) {
            String input = in.readLine();
            if (input == null || input.equals(".")) {
                break;
            }
            out.println(solveCube(input));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
        }
        log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
    }
}

/**
 * Logs a simple message.  In this case we just write the
 * message to the server applications standard output.
 */
private void log(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
}

private static class Connecter extends Thread {

/**
 * Services this thread's client by first sending the
 * client a welcome message then repeatedly reading strings
 * and sending back the capitalized version of the string.
 */
public void run() {

    try {
        System.out.println("The capitalization server is running.");
        int clientNumber = 0;
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(38300);
        try {
        while (true) {
            new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,         ex);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please mention what is the issue along with the logcat.

Comment: @PrerakSola There is no error in logcat... It just doesn't work... and yes... This is code, which sends, recieve and then sends again... It sends android to PC and from PC back to android

Comment: Try to debug the code line by line and try to find the line at which it fails.

Comment: It doesn't fail... It works... but only with wifi. And I want to do it without wifi

Comment: That is your requirement. What have you attempted to accomplish that?

Comment: I was googling it, but I didn't find anything that would fit my case... That's the reason why I am asking here on stackoverflow...